# Rails BUILD method not saving association on has_many through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, many-to-many, has-many-through

I have a Rails application setup as follows:

```
rails g model User name, password, etc....
rails g model Project title, description, etc....
rails g model Contract user:belongs_to project:belongs_to

rake db:migrate
```

Then in the console (Englishified for simplicity):

```
User.create!( params )
x = User.first.projects.build( params )
x.save
User.first.projects.to_a
[]
Project.first
[ project shows ]
```

The association on save is not working. Everything works just fine if I go directly with `User.first.projects.create( params )` but this is not what I need.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should save the `User` object after building a `project` to the user, **but not the project object**.

**If you save the `project` object after build only the `Project` will get created, but if you save the `User` object, the `project` will get assigned to the `User`.**

```
User.create!( params )

user = User.first

project = user.projects.build( params )

user.save
```

Now, you can check,

```
User.first.projects.to_a

[ project shows ]

Project.first

[ project shows ]
```

Comment: This does work, and this is a solution I am more than happy to use, but I'm still curious as to why saving a project using the build method on a user doesn't make an association, if there is information about that you may link to me I would be interested in understanding more. Anyway, thanks for your help!!